# "Can't resolve all parameters for MdDialogRef: (?)" Error when testing NG2 Material Dialog component

Tags: unit-testing, angular, typescript

I have a login component as follows:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MdDialogRef } from '@angular/material';

import { AuthService } from '../../core/services/auth.service';

@Component({
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss']
})
export class LoginDialogComponent implements OnInit {

  model: {
    email: string,
    password: string
  };
  error;

  constructor(
    private authService: AuthService,
    private dialogRef: MdDialogRef<LoginDialogComponent>
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.model = {
      email: '',
      password: ''
    };
  }

  signin() {
    this.error = null;
    this.authService.login(this.model.email, this.model.password).subscribe(data => {
      this.dialogRef.close(data);
    }, err => {
      this.error = err.json();
    });
  }

}
```

And I have a test spec for this component as follows:

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { MdDialogRef, OverlayRef  } from '@angular/material';

import { AuthService } from '../../core/services/auth.service';
import { LoginDialogComponent } from './login.component';

describe('Component: Login', () => {

    let component: LoginDialogComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<LoginDialogComponent>;

    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [
                LoginDialogComponent
            ],
            imports: [],
            providers: [
                AuthService,
                MdDialogRef,
                OverlayRef
            ]
        })
            .compileComponents();
    }));

    beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(LoginDialogComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        fixture.detectChanges();
    });

    it('should create', () => {
        expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

I've tried a million different things, and no matter what I do, I get the following error:

> Can't resolve all parameters for MdDialogRef: (?)

Here's the code for MdDialogRef, which only has 1 parameter, OverlayRef. What am I missing?

```
import { OverlayRef } from '../core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
/**
 * Reference to a dialog opened via the MdDialog service.
 */
export declare class MdDialogRef<T> {
    private _overlayRef;
    /** The instance of component opened into the dialog. */
    componentInstance: T;
    /** Subject for notifying the user that the dialog has finished closing. */
    private _afterClosed;
    constructor(_overlayRef: OverlayRef);
    /**
     * Close the dialog.
     * @param dialogResult Optional result to return to the dialog opener.
     */
    close(dialogResult?: any): void;
    /** Gets an observable that is notified when the dialog is finished closing. */
    afterClosed(): Observable<any>;
}
```

**EDIT:** taking a clue from @Ryan's comment, I tried removing the MdDialogRef provider entirely and got the following error:

> Can't resolve all parameters for OverlayRef: (?, ?, ?)

This leads me to believe that the problem is actually w/MdDialogRef trying to resolve OverlayRef, not w/MdDialogRef itself.

**WORKING EXAMPLE** The code below is the actual working code, per Yurzui's suggestion.

```
    /* tslint:disable:no-unused-variable */

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { async, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { MaterialModule, MdDialogModule, MdToolbarModule, MdDialog, MdDialogRef } from '@angular/material';

import { CoreModule } from '../../core/core.module';
import { LoginDialogComponent } from './login.component';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        LoginDialogComponent
    ],
    entryComponents: [
        LoginDialogComponent
    ],
    exports: [
        LoginDialogComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        CoreModule,
        FormsModule,
        MaterialModule.forRoot(),
        MdDialogModule.forRoot(),
        MdToolbarModule.forRoot()
    ]
})
class LoginDialogSpecModule { }

describe('Component: Login Dialog', () => {
    let component: LoginDialogComponent;
    let dialog: MdDialog;

    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [
                LoginDialogSpecModule
            ]
        });
    });

    beforeEach(() => {
        dialog = TestBed.get(MdDialog);
        let dialogRef = dialog.open(LoginDialogComponent);
        component = dialogRef.componentInstance;
    });

    it('should create', () => {
        expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

Comment: Have you tried to put MdDialogRef after OverlayRef in your providers array?

Comment: @yurzui Good guess! I hadn't tried that, but unfortunately, it didn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 7):

There is an issue *[ComponentFactoryResolver is not aware of components compiled via TestBed](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10760)*

According to this problem angular2 team offers workaround by creating real module with `entryComponents` property
https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/2.0.0-beta.1/src/lib/dialog/dialog.spec.ts#L387-L402

So your test could write like this:

```
import { MdDialog, MdDialogModule } from '@angular/material';   

@NgModule({
    declarations: [TestComponent],
    entryComponents: [TestComponent],
    exports: [TestComponent],
})
class TestModule { }

describe('Component: Login', () => {
    let component: TestComponent;
    let dialog: MdDialog;

    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [TestModule, MdDialogModule]
        });
    });

    beforeEach(() => {
        dialog = TestBed.get(MdDialog);
        let dialogRef = dialog.open(TestComponent);

        component = dialogRef.componentInstance;
    });

    it('should create', () => {
        expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/FeSbUGuqmqMiMq5qNATC?p=preview)**

Comment: Excellent! Defining the TestModule explicitly with the entryCompenents worked. My only change to your suggestion was that I had to define all my imports in the TestModule as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I was getting the same error when running my code normally, i.e. I did not write a test case.

I found that the line `provides: [ MdDialogRef ]`in my main component was giving this exact same error, and everything worked without it.

Comment: Interesting. For kicks, I removed the MdDialogRef provider in my test and got a different error: Can't resolve all parameters for OverlayRef: (?, ?, ?). This leads me to believe that the actual problem is with OverlayRef, not MdDialogRef. I'll see if this clue helps me track down the problem. Thanks.

Comment: @Dr.C.Hilarius Please let me know if you got any solution. I am having same issue

Comment: @KhanSharp Glad to know I'm not the only one! Haven't figured it out yet, but I'll update this thread as soon as I do.

Comment: I tried adding 'OverlayRef' in providers in my normal running code and also got the error 'Can't resolve all parameters for OverlayRef: (?, ?, ?)'.

Comment: I followed [this working example](https://plnkr.co/edit/n185tQbEHg1xGlNCAdxQ?p=preview) and from other articles, it looks like MdDialogRef and OverlRef cannot be passed in as providers. 

From the working example note how Material Module is imported and initialised

`import { MaterialModule } from '@angular/material'; 
...

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule, MaterialModule.forRoot() ],
  declarations: [ App, dialogs ],
  entryComponents: dialogs,
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
`

Hope this provides some clues.

Comment: They can, please try: `dialog = jasmine.createSpyObj('MdDialogRef', ['close']);` and `{ provide: MdDialogRef, useValue: dialog },` in TestBed. That worked for me at least.